# XAML: Grid Cell Overflow

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-store-apps, .net-4.5

I am trying to figure out a way that I can layout some text in a Grid, and have the contents of each cell overflow their borders.  However it seems that I can't get this to happen, and I was hoping someone knew what to do about it.

Here is an example of some code.  You can see that I included some 'ClipToBounds' properties to no avail.  The layout is the same with or without them.  Is what I am trying to do even possible?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Grid ClipToBounds="False">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
      <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="proper queen jelly" Margin="50,50,0,0" ClipToBounds="False"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

I guess it is also worth mentioning that I will eventually attempt to port the app so that it is compatible with "Windows Store Apps" in the near future.  I know there are some slight differences between that and WPF, so I guess I was wondering how this would work for both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your point, but perhaps you are looking for the `Grid.RowSpan` attribute. Your textblock will look like this:

`<TextBlock Grid.RowSpan="2" FontSize="50"  Text="proper queen jelly" Margin="50,50,0,0" ClipToBounds="False"/>`

Comment: Well that technically works, but causes a bunch of other issues if I want to do things like change the vertical alignments, etc.  I am looking for something a little more robust.